# Returning HashMap from native method

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I need to return a HashMap from Android native implementation. On Running the app I am getting following crash:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
```

Below are implementation details.

Method signature on Java side:

```
private native HashMap<String, Double> testBitmapJNI(Bitmap bitmap);
```

in C++ code:

```
static const JNINativeMethod g_NativeMethods[] = {
     ....
     {"testBitmapJNI", "(Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;)Ljava/util/HashMap;", 
         (void*)testBitmapJNI},
     ....
 };



jobject testBitmapJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject instance, jobject bitmap){

   jobject myHashMap= ... 

   /* every thing is working good here */
   return myHashMap;
}
```

If I change the signature of testBitmapJNI to return void, it no longer crashes. I believe the signature in mapping table is not correct. It will be great if someone can suggest the correct signature to use in the table or another approach to fix / implement the same.

Comment: `jobject myHashMap= ...` and `/* every thing is working good here */`?!?!  How do you know it's "working good"?  You don't know why it's not working else you wouldn't be asking the question.  Post all the code.

Comment: How do you create the **myHashMap** object? Is it really a `HashMap<String, Double>`?

Comment: One problem could be that you don't create (boxing) `Double` value. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501229/c-returning-hashmapstring-boolean-object-to-java. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591185/convert-c-map-to-jobject-jni there is a mini-example of returning a Map from C++ to Java.

Comment: I've done a lot of JNI work, and there is ample opportunity for things to go wrong. One thing to note: convert all of your java objects (both key and value) that are going to go into the hashmap, into global references, and delete the original local references. This will solve two potential problems: (1) running out of local references (2) storing local references persistently.  And post all of your code.